# What is wrong with my "won" function

Tags: c, cs50

I am working on PSET3 of Harvard CS50 online and having problems with the "won" function for CS50 game of fifteen.

The function works fine with a 4x4 grid puzzle but not with 3x3

The function returns `true` a couple of steps too early in case of a 3x3.

The function is required to look through a 2D array for numbers in ascending order from 1 to 8 for a 3x3 size game and 1 to 15 in a 4x4 size game with the last element of the array being zero.

My thought process for the code is that i set the counter initially to 1 and check it against the first element of the array. If it matches then increase the counter by 1 and repeat for the next element.

If the counter reaches the total number of elements in the array it returns true and, if the counter does not match the corresponding array element at any time it returns false.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

```
/**
 * Returns true if game is won (i.e., board is in winning configuration)
 * else false.
 */
bool won(void)
{
    // TODO

    int counter = 1;

    for (int i=0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < d; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == counter) 
            {
                counter++;
            }
            if (counter == (d*d)) 
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) There's no way all this code is needed.

Comment: Klutt, Thanks a lot for the advice, I am afraid I am new to stackoverflow and to coding/CS. I will learn both coding and the stackoverflow code of conduct :-)

Comment: this statement: `int board[DIM_MAX][DIM_MAX];` always produces a 9x9 matrix, and the `move()` function is not taking into account when the actual 'populated' matrix is smaller.

Comment: You only need to show the `won()` function to get an answer. The rest of the code just gets in the way.

Answer (score 1):

Your `won` routine returns true if all the elements are in order, ignoring the element with value zero. Thus, if the elements are:

```
1 2 3
_ 4 5
6 7 8
```

Then your code will increment `counter` when it sees 1, 2, and 3. It will not increment `counter` when it sees the 0 where `_` is shown above. Then it will increment `counter` when it sees 4, 5, 6, 7, and 8. Then `counter` is 9, so it equals `d*d`, and `won` returns true.

Fundamentally, your `won` routine is too flexible. At each step, it increments `counter` if the current element equals `counter`—but it is passive otherwise. That is, it continues examination even if the desired condition was not met. Since there is only one “winning” position, if any element is out of position, you can return `false` as soon as you see it.

Comment: That worked! new code for the function is bool won(void)
{
    // TODO

    int counter = 1;

    for (int i=0; i < d; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < d; j++)
        {
            if (board[i][j] == 0)
            counter = 0;

            if (board[i][j] != counter)
                return false;

        counter++;

        }
    }
            return true;
}